# What is my phone doing at 1 o'clock in the morning?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, battery-life

I have recently installed JuiceDefender (JD) and along with it JuicePlotter (JP). JP gives me a nice graph about my energy consumption over time. I noticed that around 1 A.M. my phone uses up more battery power than the rest of the night. I don't think that I have something explicitly scheduled at that time. I have Samsungs 2.2 Froyo (rooted) on my Samsung Galaxy-S (I9000).

How can I find out the cause for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a logcat viewer, such as [LogCat Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) (I've found that one works well), and just scroll back through the logs until the time in question.

A less precise solution would be to go to **Settings > About phone > Battery use** and that will tell you what has been using most of your battery.

Comment: I have finally found some time to quickly look at the log, that I recorded. I guess, I will need some more time to comb through the log...

Comment: yeah, it can be tedious with all the information there, but that definitely should contain your problem.

Answer (score 4):

When you get Gingerbread on your Galaxy S, then the battery usage graph shows what's using power over time

**Settings** -> **About Phone** -> **Battery Use** and then press on the graph at the top for a more detailed view broken down by app over time. *(you can also get there through Settings -> Applications -> Battery Use and then pressing on the graph at the top)*.

(Don't know if this is a Samsung or a Gingerbread feature but is part of Samsung's official Gingerbread 2.3.3. release for the Galaxy S which was released a few weeks ago in many countries/networks)

Comment: I rebooted into windows and checked, if Kies wants to install Gingerbread on my device. So far, they do not offer me to install it, but I am looking forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

If there's anything happening at a "given time", or otherwise should show some "significant change", it might also be worth to take a look at [SystemPanel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel):

[image: SystemPanel] [image: SystemPanel]
<sup>SystemPanel (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel))</sup>

Even the free version allows you to live-monitor your Android system (where "live" means the app must be running), while the payed version adds a "monitoring service" which stores collected information, so you can refer to it later. As above screenshot shows, it lets you clearly see the peaks for CPU (click the image to enlarge), but also for battery and other ressources. It also allows you to pick the "top processes" and see how they behaved over time.

Clearly a candidate to investigate the problem you described.

Comment: Yupp -- good luck with it! Though I hope your problem has been solved meanwhile, so it's rather "good to know" and "just in case" for you I guess ;)

Comment: Yes, the problem no longer persists after a factory reset and reinstalling most of the programs (I never figured out, what happened though). Also I moved on to another phone and SystemPanel + Better Battery Stats should enable me to get the most out of the battery life.